# Color gradient for bars in simple bar chart and ordinal catagories

Tags: json, visualization, vega-lite

I simply cannot seem to change the colors of a bar chart over ordinal categories.
I was able to give every bar a different color by setting the color encoding with a ordinal type. However it defaults to the blues color scheme. I want the range of colors to be different. Let's say from #FFFFFF to #000000. I could not discover how to provide my own such colors on which the color gradient will be based. Anyone got a clue?

This is what I tried:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 28}, {"a": "B", "b": 55}, {"a": "C", "b": 43},
      {"a": "D", "b": 91}, {"a": "E", "b": 81}, {"a": "F", "b": 53},
      {"a": "G", "b": 19}, {"a": "H", "b": 87}, {"a": "I", "b": 52}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}},
    "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {"field": "a", "type": "ordinal"}
  }
}
```

And this is how it looks like:
[Example bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Owa9k.png)

As you can see, it simply gives a blue color range. How do I provide my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 28}, {"a": "B", "b": 55}, {"a": "C", "b": 43},
      {"a": "D", "b": 91}, {"a": "E", "b": 81}, {"a": "F", "b": 53},
      {"a": "G", "b": 19}, {"a": "H", "b": 87}, {"a": "I", "b": 52}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}},
    "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {"field": "a", "type": "ordinal" ,"scale":{"scheme":["blue", "red"], "interpolate":"cubehelix"}}
  }
}
```

Comment: This alternates between two colors. What I would like to see is a gardient where A is blue and I is red, and everything in between is blend of blue that gets progressively more red.

Comment: I'll update now. Please mark as solved and/or upvote if you found the answer helpful